How to use iOS main code inside common main code in KMM?
I have a KMM project with shared UI. I am trying to implement something native in both Android and iOS. so I have a swift class that exists in iOS main module and I want to use it inside kotlin code in  ios Main module.
here is my swift code:
@objc class Employee: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String
    @objc var age: Int

    @objc init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    @objc func description() -> String {
        return "\(name) is \(age) years old."
    }
}

and I have a Kotlin class in iOS main that I want to use the swift class in it.
class Caller {
    val emp = Employee() //unresolved Reference Employee
    actual fun description(): String {
        // emp.
        return ""
    }
}

the issue here is that I'm getting an error "unresolved Reference Employee".

it's not possible as iosMain is dependant on commonMain not commonMain Dependant on iosMain. underStand flow that what's on top and what's below.

You can't directly access Swift or Swift-based commands from commonMain (without some annoying c-interop that no-one understands), but you can in iosMain. You just have to use Kotlin syntax.
// iosMain/Employee.kt
class Employee(var name: String, var age: Int): NSObject {
    override fun description(): String = "$name is $age years old."
}

However, you need expect/actual functions to be able to access the iosMain object from commonMain. Unfortunately, you still can't use NSObject from commonMain because NSObject is not available for Android or Kotlin Native.
This is all for naught.  There's no need to create an NSObject when Kotlin will do if for you during compile.
My recommendation is a structure like so:
// commonMain/Employee.kt
expect class Employee(var name: String, var age: Int) {
    fun description(): String
}

// iosMain/Employee.kt
actual class Employee(var name: String, var age: Int) {
    actual fun description(): String = "$name is $age years old."
}

// commonMain/Caller.kt
class Caller {
    val emp = Employee("Joe", 30)
    val description = emp.description() // "Joe is 30 years old"
}

